# How to extract not nullable property names from type?

Tags: typescript

I would like to define a mapped conditional type so that I can extract property names from type that can have `null` value e.g.

```
interface Person {
   name: string
   age: number 
   category: string | null
}

type NotNullablePersonProps = NotNullablePropertyNames<Person> 
// NotNullablePersonProps should be "name" | "age"
```

I have looked at the [following example](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23126#issuecomment-395929162):

```
type OptionalPropertyNames<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]-?: undefined extends T[K] ? K : never
}[keyof T];

type RequiredPropertyNames<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]-?: undefined extends T[K] ? never : K
}[keyof T];
```

I was not able to adapt it to the case with `null` properties though.

How do I defined `NotNullablePropertyNames` mapped conditional type to return all property names that cannot be `null`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing `undefined` with `null` in the code you provided works as expected, provided you have `strictNullChecks` enables. Without that option `string | null` is just `string` so  there is nothing to extract

```
interface Person {
   name: string
   age: number 
   category: string | null
}

type NotNullablePersonProps = NotNullablePropertyNames<Person> // name | age

type NotNullablePropertyNames<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]-?: null extends T[K] ? never : K
}[keyof T];
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Person%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20%5E%20here%20check%20strictNullChecks%20%0D%0A%20%20%20name%3A%20string%0D%0A%20%20%20age%3A%20number%20%0D%0A%20%20%20category%3A%20string%20%7C%20null%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20NotNullablePersonProps%20%3D%20NotNullablePropertyNames%3CPerson%3E%20%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20NotNullablePropertyNames%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5BK%20in%20keyof%20T%5D-%3F%3A%20null%20extends%20T%5BK%5D%20%3F%20never%20%3A%20K%0D%0A%7D%5Bkeyof%20T%5D%3B)